# map US state name to two letter acronyms that was given in dictionary separately

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose now I have a `dataframe` with 2 columns: State and City.

Then I have a separate `dict` with the two-letter acronym for each state. Now I want to add a third column to map state name with its two-letter acronym. What should I do in Python/Pandas? For instance the sample question is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
a = pd.Series({'State': 'Ohio', 'City':'Cleveland'})
b = pd.Series({'State':'Illinois', 'City':'Chicago'})
c = pd.Series({'State':'Illinois', 'City':'Naperville'})
d = pd.Series({'State': 'Ohio', 'City':'Columbus'})
e = pd.Series({'State': 'Texas', 'City': 'Houston'})
f = pd.Series({'State': 'California', 'City': 'Los Angeles'})
g = pd.Series({'State': 'California', 'City': 'San Diego'})
state_city = pd.DataFrame([a,b,c,d,e,f,g])
state_2 = {'OH': 'Ohio','IL': 'Illinois','CA': 'California','TX': 'Texas'}
```

Now I have to map the column State in the `df` `state_city` using the dictionary of `state_2`. The mapped `df` `state_city` should contain three columns: `state`, `city`, and `state_2letter`.

The original dataset I had had multiple columns with nearly all US major cities.

Therefore it will be less efficient to do it manually. Is there any easy way to do it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For one, it's probably easier to store the key-value pairs like `state name: abbreviation` in your dictionary, like this:

```
state_2 = {'Ohio': 'OH', 'Illinois': 'IL', 'California': 'CA', 'Texas': 'TX'}
```

You can achieve this easily:

```
state_2 = {state: abbrev for state, abbrev in state_2.items()}
```

Using `pandas.DataFrame.map`:

```
>>> state_city['abbrev'] = state_city['State'].map(state_2)
>>> state_city
          City       State abbrev
0    Cleveland        Ohio     OH
1      Chicago    Illinois     IL
2   Naperville    Illinois     IL
3     Columbus        Ohio     OH
4      Houston       Texas     TX
5  Los Angeles  California     CA
6    San Diego  California     CA
```

Comment: Should not we change the mapping function to `state_2 = {state: abbrev for state, abbrev in state_2.items()}`?

Comment: Yes!!Your suggestion worked, otherwise I kept getting NANs.

Answer (score 1):

I do agree with @blacksite that the `state_2` dictionary should map its values like that:

`state_2 = {'Ohio': 'OH','Illinois': 'IL','California': 'CA','Texas': 'TX'}`

Then using `pandas.DataFrame.replace`

```
state_city['state_2letter'] = state_city.State.replace(state_2)
state_city

|-|State      |City         |state_2letter|
|-|-----      |------       |----------|
|0| Ohio      | Cleveland   |   OH|
|1| Illinois  | Chicago     |   IL|
|2| Illinois  | Naperville  |   IL|
|3| Ohio      | Columbus    |   OH|
|4| Texas     | Houston     |   TX|
|5| California| Los Angeles |   CA|
|6| California| San Diego   |   CA|
```