# python sub state names for abbrev via python dict with re.sub

Tags: python, regex, dictionary, text, python-re

I have a dataframe with a column in it containing state names.  The names are a mix of official abbreviations and partial spellings and complete state names.

```
d = pd.DataFrame(['fla', 'fl', 'del', 'ohio', 'calif', 'ca', 'del', 'texas', 'miss', 'tx', 'new mex'],
                 columns = ["state"])
```

There is a python dict with state abbrevs and names here: https://code.activestate.com/recipes/577305-python-dictionary-of-us-states-and-territories/

I would like to look in the dataframe `d` and find the best match in the `dict` and substitute for the values in `d['state']`.  I don't think I want to use `replace` because i want to replace the "whole word" rather than the substring. The desired result:

```
d = ['fl', 'fl', 'de', 'oh', 'ca', 'ca', 'de', 'tx', 'ms', 'tx', 'nm']
```

Loading the dict directly into my console, and calling it `states_dict`, I tried the following (based on this [map US state name to two letter acronyms that was given in dictionary separately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40814187/map-us-state-name-to-two-letter-acronyms-that-was-given-in-dictionary-separately/40814212))

```
d['state'] = d['state'].map(states_dict)
```

which produced `nan` for every entry in my dataframe, `d`.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: `map` is going to look for an exact match.  Is the capitalization all identical?  Also, `map` isn't going to look for a substring.  The whole string has to match.

Comment: @TimRoberts ok well perhaps I'm looking for a `regex` then?  i need to be able to account for the partial strings like 'calif' and 'miss' in `d['state']`.  should i be using `re.sub` instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems to work: search for the state name by taking each value from `d['state']` and adding `\w*` between every letter and use `match` to search from the beginning of each dictionary value in a case insensitive way. Once found, return the found value lowercased.

And I think `miss` must be `mo`, not `mx`.

```py
import pandas as pd
import re
d = pd.DataFrame(['fla', 'fl', 'del', 'ohio', 'calif', 'ca', 'del', 'texas', 'miss', 'tx', 'new mex', 'NY', 'NJ', 'NM', 'NC'], columns = ["state"])
states = {
        'AK': 'Alaska',
        'AL': 'Alabama',
        'AR': 'Arkansas',
        'AS': 'American Samoa',
        'AZ': 'Arizona',
        'CA': 'California',
        'CO': 'Colorado',
        'CT': 'Connecticut',
        'DC': 'District of Columbia',
        'DE': 'Delaware',
        'FL': 'Florida',
        'GA': 'Georgia',
        'GU': 'Guam',
        'HI': 'Hawaii',
        'IA': 'Iowa',
        'ID': 'Idaho',
        'IL': 'Illinois',
        'IN': 'Indiana',
        'KS': 'Kansas',
        'KY': 'Kentucky',
        'LA': 'Louisiana',
        'MA': 'Massachusetts',
        'MD': 'Maryland',
        'ME': 'Maine',
        'MI': 'Michigan',
        'MN': 'Minnesota',
        'MO': 'Missouri',
        'MP': 'Northern Mariana Islands',
        'MS': 'Mississippi',
        'MT': 'Montana',
        'NA': 'National',
        'NC': 'North Carolina',
        'ND': 'North Dakota',
        'NE': 'Nebraska',
        'NH': 'New Hampshire',
        'NJ': 'New Jersey',
        'NM': 'New Mexico',
        'NV': 'Nevada',
        'NY': 'New York',
        'OH': 'Ohio',
        'OK': 'Oklahoma',
        'OR': 'Oregon',
        'PA': 'Pennsylvania',
        'PR': 'Puerto Rico',
        'RI': 'Rhode Island',
        'SC': 'South Carolina',
        'SD': 'South Dakota',
        'TN': 'Tennessee',
        'TX': 'Texas',
        'UT': 'Utah',
        'VA': 'Virginia',
        'VI': 'Virgin Islands',
        'VT': 'Vermont',
        'WA': 'Washington',
        'WI': 'Wisconsin',
        'WV': 'West Virginia',
        'WY': 'Wyoming'
}

def best_match(x):
    if len(x) == 2: # Try another way for 2-letter codes
        for a,n in states.items():
            if len(n.split()) == 2:
                if "".join([c[0] for c in n.split()]).lower() == x.lower():
                    return a.lower()
    new_rx = re.compile(r"\w*".join([ch for ch in x]), re.I)
    for a,n in states.items():
        if new_rx.match(n):
            return a.lower()
        
d['state_corrected'] = d['state'].apply(lambda x: best_match(x))
```

**Results**:

```py
      state state_corrected
0       fla              fl
1        fl              fl
2       del              de
3      ohio              oh
4     calif              ca
5        ca              ca
6       del              de
7     texas              tx
8      miss              mo
9        tx              tx
10  new mex              nm
11       NY              ny
12       NJ              nj
13       NM              nm
14       NC              nc
```

Comment: This is great.  One question:  how to deal with Missouri vs. Mississippi?

Comment: @jvalenti It is a 1M dollar question. Unfortunately, I doubt it can be resolved easily.

Comment: Also...why does adding a character between each letter work?  would you mind explaining a little more...still learning python.

Comment: @jvalenti `\w*` = `word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _) (0 or more times (matching the most amount possible))`. This is to consume unknown letters between the known letters if any.

Comment: Yeah, you can't really look for partial matches.  There's no way to separate MI from Mich or Missouri or Minn or Mississippi.  I think you have to look for exact matches on common abbreviations and reject the rest.  Even "Miss" could be either common Mississippi or the start of Missouri.  Even a human being couldn't do it.

Comment: OK, so I ran into a slight problem where this doesn't work for states like NY, NJ and NC, strangely--values of `None` are produced for NY, NJ, NM, NC

Comment: @jvalenti I added some logic to process two-word entries.

Comment: This works now, I had to fiddle with my data a bit prior but now it works perfectly thank you so much!